# Can jimp handle slightly broken images?

Tags: node.js, jimp

I've just moved away from using `sharp` because it has problems with BMP images some of my users try to load, and I picked `jimp`. All good, except it's not very tolerant with images that aren't quite right.

One of my users tried to load a PNG file from "Snip & Sketch" on Windows, and jimp reported "Error: unrecognised content at end of stream".

I hit the file with `pngcheck`, and that went like this:

```
$ pngcheck ~/dodgy.png 
/path/to/dodgy.png  additional data after IEND chunk
ERROR: /path/to/dodgy.png
```

So jimp is reporting the right thing, but can I get it to ignore the rubbish after the `IEND` chunk?